# Access remote hive table from Spark with Kerberos

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hive, kerberos

I am running in spark in cluster 1 and there is a different cluster where I have hive running. In my spark job, I want to access the remote Hive table. I can access the cluster 1's hive using `spark.sql`. But for the remote hive, I can not do so. Hence I thought of using a JDBC connection.

The second cluster's Hive is Kerberos authenticated. When I try to connect to the remote hive with JDBC and Kerberos it fails with `GSS initiate exception`. I am sending `spark.kerberos.prinicipal|keytab` in spark-submit.

```
df = spark.read \
        .format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", "jdbc:hive2://<hive fqdn>:10000/default;principal=hive/_HOST@DOMAINL;auth=Kerberos;kerberosAuthType=fromSubject") \
        .option("query", "SQL") \
        .option("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver") \
        .load()
```

If I try to add principal and keytab in the JDBC option I get:
`Empty list of JDBC connection providers for the specified driver options`. This is mostly coz this [SPARK-31815](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-31815) was closed and not implemented.

I also sent the keytab file using --files for it to be available on executors still no luck.

Spark version = 3.2.0
Platform = K8s and YARN

Any help on getting it to work will be helpful.

Comment: Just to update, by passing the /tmp/krb5cc_uid file I am able to connect, but that cache will get invalidated, my job is long running.